# Calculating max affordable of repeatable purchase with arbitrary cost function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm working on a program that takes an arbitrary formula with a single variable in it, such as $100*x^{1.05}$, which represents the current cost of a repeatable purchase in a video game (x being the number of purchases already made) and calculates how many purchases you can currently make with a certain amount of resources. For performance reasons, I'm trying to calculate this value directly, rather than making a purchase, checking if I can afford another, and repeating.

For the example I showed above, it's a simple geometric series and that's easy enough. For the general case I know I can find the inverse of the function in order to get the last purchase with a cost less than the amount of resources owned. However, that's *not* how many they could actually purchase, because it doesn't take into account the resources already spent on previous upgrades.

I think what I need to do here is integrate the function, but it's a bit different from your typical area under the curve problem - rather than having the left and right bounds and calculating the area under the curve, I *know* the area under the curve (the amount of resources we have to spent) and the left bound (the amount of purchases already made), and am trying to calculate the right bound (the max amount of purchases currently affordable). Additionally I'm not positive an integral will properly handle the fact that purchases are made in discrete operations rather than being continuous. I can floor the value at the end, but that doesn't account for the integral being smoothed between each of the integer values.

To put it another way, if the original function is $f(x)$, and I know I can calculate $f^{-1}(x)$ as well as $\int{f(x)}$, could I calculate the upper x bound in an area under the curve function if I know what the area should be.